# How do I add :cached or :delegated into a docker-compose.yml volumes list?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Title says it all. I've got a few volumes set up as readonly (`:ro`) but want to test `:cached` and `:delegated` for helping with file i/o performance, but couldn't figure out how to set this up in a compose file.

Oh, I already tested:

`volumes:
 - external:internal:cached`

Comment: I tried the same (just append `:cached`) and got a `Mounts denied: 9p: Stack overflow` error on osx.

Comment: I asked the same question on github: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1592#issuecomment-300141156

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Explanation**: The purpose of using `volumes` configuration on docker is to share data between the host and the docker container and ensure data consistency between both (What happens in **A**(host/container) is represented in **B**(host/container) and vice versa) . The mounted volume is "part" of the container and relevant. The common usage is to store shared data backup both in container and on file system in machine. If the container is removed, volume still exists and is independent of container state it will be reused and loaded from last persisted state.

**TLDR:**

- Use `cached`: when the host performs changes, the container is in read only mode.
- Use `delegated`: when docker container performs changes, host is in read
  only mode.
- Use `default`: When both container and host actively and
  continuously perform changes on data.
- Ensure you use an updated docker-compose and docker version on your machine

**From Documentation**:

> **Mac uses `osxfs` to propagate directories and files shared from macOS to the Linux VM. This propagation makes these directories and files available to Docker containers** running on Docker Desktop for Mac.
> **By default, these shares are fully-consistent, meaning that every time a write happens on the macOS host or through a mount in a container, the changes are flushed to disk so that all participants in the share have a fully-consistent view.
>
> Full consistency can severely impact performance in some cases.**
> Docker 17.05 and higher introduce options to tune the consistency
> setting on a per-mount, per-container basis. The following options are
> available:
>
> The `consistency` option, if present, may be one of `consistent`, `delegated`, or `cached`. This setting only applies to Docker Desktop for Mac, and is ignored on all other platforms.

**The Docker volumes flags are:**

1. `consistent` or `default`: The default setting with full consistency, as described above.
2. `delegated`: The container runtime’s view of the mount is authoritative. There may be delays before updates made in a container are visible on the host.
   **When you use it**? For example You use it when the container changes the data continuously and you want to backup this data on the host, this is read only operation on host perspective and therefore the right choice would be delegated.
3. `cached`: The macOS host’s view of the mount is authoritative. There may be delays before updates made on the host are visible within a container. **When you use it?** For example when your host continuously changes data that the container service reads and uses it ( like configuration / source code / rendered data from server etc ...)

**Usage**:

```
- <my-first-host-volume>:<first-container-volume-path>:delegated
- <my-second-host-volume>:<second-container-volume-path>:cached
```

**Example**:

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  jenkins:
     image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
     environment:
       - JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
     container_name: jenkins  
     volumes:
       - '~/jenkins/:/var/jenkins_home:delegated'
       - '~/environment_keys:/var/data:cached'
     ports:
       - 0.0.0.0:8080:8080
     expose:
       - 5000  
     restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation for this on the docker-compose website. Could you please provide a link

Comment: @goonerify docker-compose documentation Link : https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Thanks but there are no references to docker volume flags like `consistent`, `default`, `delegated` and `cached` in that link

Comment: @goonerify I think that these directives are no longer applicable. I can find many articles dating 2018/19 that reference these, but no official documentation mentions it anywhere.

Comment: http://docs.docker.oeynet.com/compose/compose-file/#caching-options-for-volume-mounts-docker-for-mac

Comment: Did they remove the volume flags? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Docker documentation issue about this. Not documented on Docker Compose (but works on Docker Desktop for Mac 4.0.0) https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/11884

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I wanted a `readonly` (`:ro`) volume that’s also `:cached` or `:delegated`. To do this, you simply use this syntax:

```
volumes:
 - /external/folder:/internal/folder:ro,cached
```

Comment: Why would you use `cached` in combination with ro? My understanding from the docker documentation is that `delegated` is faster if you don't need additional write consistency guarantees from the container to host, and with ro you'd never write out again?

Comment: @Hultner In my case, it was a hot-reloaded source-code folder that was then picked up by `webpack-dev-server`. I wanted to use `ro` because the container should never need to write to this folder, and `cached` because I don’t mind the occasional save causing a delay. However, I’d mind it if the way more frequent reads are delayed due to syncing taking place.

"As such, **`cached` typically improves the performance of read-heavy workloads**, at the cost of some temporary inconsistency between the host and the container." is why I believe it’s best, but the docs aren’t exactly clear about it.

Comment: As I grasp it from the docs delegated provides even better performance if we can live with delays from writes within the container and cached only adds extra benefit if we want writes from the container to propagate to the host.

"`delegated:` The container runtime’s view of the mount is authoritative. There may be delays before updates made in a container are visible on the host."

and

"…writes by containers may not be immediately reflected on the host… However, by relinquishing consistency, **delegated mounts offer significantly better performance than the other configurations.**"

Comment: @Hultner have you tried this for live development with setups like webpack, etc? Did you not have any problems with hot reloading / bundling etc?

Comment: @gen Yes I have, I used it in production at a previous client and it worked great, both for me and the rest of the team. I'd say much better performance then without using delegated.

Answer (score 9):

I was not running new enough (edge channel) version of Docker so the commands did not work. After upgrading, everything worked as expected.

Comment: In my case, it worked after a restart... So the syntax is OK :-)

Comment: what version was `cached` added to docker?

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees restart of what? Docker or the containers?

Comment: Restart of the whole docker engine.

Answer (score 8):

I felt that this thread needed to be updated to reflect the current situation better.

Ever since Docker for Mac started including gRPC-FUSE, these flags have been removed from the Docker documentation as they're no longer needed. It's safe to remove them from your docker-compose.yml files.

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5402

You can see gRPC-FUSE is selected by default within Docker Desktop. Go to Settings > General tab.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is not directly related to the question but serves the same purpose.

The [docker-sync](http://docker-sync.io/) project aims at solving those problems of slow syncs on macOS and Windows. I have set it up for some Ruby on Rails app and the results were astonishing. The results should be the same for other types of projects.

Here is my template dockerfile-compose

```yaml
version: '3.4'
volumes:
  app-code:
    external: true
services:
  backend:
    volumes:
      - app-code/:/app:rw
```

And the docker-sync file

```
version: 2
syncs:
  app-code:
    src: './'
    sync_strategy: 'native_osx'
    sync_excludes:
      - '.git'
      - 'coverage'
      - '.gitignore'
    watch_excludes:
      - '.*/.git'
      - '.gitignore'
      - 'log'
      - 'docker-*.yml'
```

Then you can `docker-sync start` or follow the documentation to use docker-sync instead of `docker-compose` to automatically start/stop the sync when needed.

One of the main disadvantages is the dependency with the docker-sync gem that you must install on your OS, but once it's set up it works wonderfully.

Comment: If you're using the docker-sync file above as reference, don't forget to fix the quote typo if .gitignore entry in sync_excludes.